# Preview of Google Map links in chat

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, chat

If you paste a link to travel wiki or other SE questions into the chat, a preview image is automatically created. I would really like the same for Google map links.

A lot of time we're discussing something in the chat and it would be really cool if a mini map is displayed if you copy a link to a Google map.

What do you think about this?

**EDIT (16/4/2012)**

Unfortunately there is no news yet. Do you know where I can place an official feature request? On Meta SO?

**EDIT (30/04/2014)**

Any news on this?

**EDIT (22/04/2015)**
This would still be very interesting. Did I tag it correctly?

Answer (score 11):

I think it'd be fantastic.  Even if it's just a simple 400x400 simple mode map, that'd be enough to see and discuss.

Of course, do we limit it to Google? What about Bing Maps or Open Street Maps? ;)

Comment: Bing maps? Who uses *that*?

Comment: Er, when I worked at Microsoft we used it, and Bing search ;)

Comment: It does have a cool 2.5D birds-eye view that Google Maps lacks.

Comment: But it also lacks most of the world. Google Maps has even finally begun to work to a degree here in Georgia, which it didn't last year.

Comment: Google Maps sucked in Central Asia.  Bring on OpenStreetMaps support :)

Comment: Yes I hope it will be possible to do it. Last time it was done very fast (within hours) ;)

Comment: OpenStreetMaps is great for details and being able to contribute, but I don't find it so good for overviews of larger areas, and of course it doesn't have aerial/satellite imagery. Bing Maps lacks aerial/satellite imagery with any detail in my current area (Georgia). Google Maps is simply the best all-around tool.

Comment: Re: "2.5D birds-eye view", browse to maps.google.com, click "Earth" and then the "Tilt the view" button below the compass rose :P