# Google Maps if someone enters coordinates in the chat

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, chat

Similar to the feature request I placed in [this question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/491/693), I would like to propose another feature request.

Whenever someone enters coordinates like that in the chat:

> 49° 14′ 0″ N, 7° 0′ 0″ E

It would be very sexy to see a Google Maps preview of this coordinates.

**EDIT (30/04/2014)**

Any news on this?

**EDIT (22/04/2015)**

Any news?

Comment: Or openstreetmap.

Comment: Updated tags to bump this up. Is there any other more efficient way to ping community mods?

Comment: @pnuts Yes but not a community mod. We need one of the higher-ups from the dev team.

Answer (score 2):

*very sexy* to me does not seem a very strong argument. And again there is the issue, only for Travel or across all sites? GIS might want it if we got it but SO might not and SE in general do not seem to favour (IMO very understandably) a lot of site customisation.

I presume there have been some co-ordinates posted in "We Are Here" but I don't recall even one instance from the last several months.

Plus, it is not exceptionally onerous to copy and paste into Google Maps (though I would agree, may slow the 'pace' of chat at times).

And, I would rather the [bug] backlog were cleared up first.